# Advanced Custom Fields, access to a field's title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Woocommerce with Advanced Custom Fields.

I've added a repeater field to products, which will have children fields of type (File). I need to get the titles of these children File type fields.

I tried getting the product's ID `$current_product_id = get_post_meta( get_the_id());` and doing `var_dump($current_product_id);`, but I am not getting the human readable title for the fields, I'm only able to get the computer readable title, and the parent (repeater) field's title.

Here's a screenshot of how the custom field looks like:
[image]

I need the titles "Spec Sheets" and "IES Files", currently I'm only able to get "spec_sheets" and "ies_files"

If anyone can give any solutions/hints that would be appreciated.
Please let me know if you need any more info.

thanks!

Comment: Try get_field("repeater_field_name", get_the_id())

Comment: @NarekMalkhasyan I tried the following: ```$testt=get_field("spec_sheets", get_the_id()); var_dump($testt);``` It didn't include the human readable titles. Thanks, though!